# Cannot drop control onto aspx file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

As of a couple of days ago, in any Visual Studio Web Application, I cannot drag a control from the toolbox and drop it onto an aspx file; it just shows the slash/circle do-not-drop cursor. This happens even with a new web application. I've been doing this for years and now it doesn't work. Is there a setting that can cause this?

Comment: Is it only in design view or also in source view?

Comment: Ok, have you tried repairing your VS? I know this is a hassle but is the only thing that I could suggest

Comment: I just tried it -- no change.

Comment: Hey, after a little research I've found [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/633053/error-in-visual-web-developer-10-error-creating-control-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component). Apparently removing ESET Nod 32 Smart Security 5 from your computer will fix it, only if you have that installed of course

Comment: No, only have MSE on Windows 7.